# displaying message in PyQt4

Tags: python

I am developing an application using PyQt4 .

Currently I am in need of a message box ie if I am on a current screen and user presses a function the callback function should display message whether by a message box or any other way you can suggest ......However when the user cancels it the flow should go to the current screen.

Please help ....

Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood your question, I believe your scenario is the common one.

In order to show a message, the easiest way is:

```
my_msg = "Hello world"
QtGui.QMessageBox.information(None, 'My Title', my_msg)
```

This code should be in the callback function you have mention.